# Structure constants of Lie algebra from system of linear equations

Tags: lie-algebras

The [Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) in terms of the [structure constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants)   $c_{p,q}^r$
of an $N$-dimensional Lie algebra with  $p,q,r=1,\ldots,N$  reads
$$  J_{i,j,k}^l \equiv c_{i,j}^m \, c_{k,m}^l + 
        c_{j,k}^m \, c_{i,m}^l + c_{k,i}^m \, c_{j,m}^l = 0   $$
(Einstein summation convention is implied.)
Since the structure constants are anti-symmetric,
$c_{p,q}^r = -c_{q,p}^r$,
we only need to consider the
$N^2 \cdot (N-1) \cdot (N-2) \; / \; 6$  equations 
$J_{i,j,k}^l =0$ with 
$i = 1,\ldots,N \quad j=i+1,\ldots,N \quad 
k=j+1,\ldots,N \quad l=1,\ldots,N$.

Recently, Paiva and Teixeira ([arxiv:1108.4396](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/1108.4396)) argued that,
if the  $N\cdot(N-1)$  structure constants  $c_{p=1,q}^r$  are given, 
the system of
$N \cdot (N-1) \cdot (N-2)\;/\;2$  equations
$$  J_{i=1,j,k}^l = 0 $$
with $j=2,\ldots,N \quad k=j+1,\ldots,N \quad l=1,\ldots,N$ 
is linear in the unknown structure constants 
and 
(provided the system $J_{i=1,j,k}^l = 0$ is not degenerate)
can be solved to determine all remaining unknowns $c_{p>1,q}^r$.

Interestingly, the 
$N \cdot (N-1) \cdot (N-2) \cdot (N-3) \; / \; 6$
equations
$$  J_{i>1,j,k}^l = 0 $$
with $i=2,\ldots,N \quad j=i+1,\ldots,N 
\quad k=j+1,\ldots,N \quad l=1,\ldots,N$
(which are quadratic in $c_{p,q}^r$) appear to be redundant.

Is there a simple explanation for this redundancy?